# Avoid re-fetching after re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

The problem with my code is whenever I click toggle, the `Child` component re-render and request to the API gets called again. What I want is to request once, use that data even after re-rendering.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/goofy-sunset-8srh6g?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A3%2C1-28%2C1)

```
function Child() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching some data from server");
    setData(`this number should not change: ${Math.random().toString()}`);
  }, []);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}

export default function Parent() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const onToggle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onToggle}>Toggle</button>
      {toggle && <Child />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: On what basis should the code decide if it needs to re-fetch or not?

Comment: It should only fetch on first render (when data is empty)

Comment: So have `useEffect` check that to decide whether or not to do the fetching.

Comment: Remember too that React will *always* render your components **at least** *twice* in development mode, in part to smoke out exactly this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are not just re-rendering, infact you are re-mounting your `Child` component when you click the toggle button. If you want to not trigger the API call again, you should not re-mount the component.

So, what you have to do is to remove the conditional check in `{toggle && <Child />}` and replace it with `<Child` />

Then you can modify it slightly, by pass the toggle state to the `Child` component like `<Child show={toggle}/>` and then return `null` from `Child` in cases where you previously did not want to render it.

```js
function Child(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching some data from server");
    setData(`this number should not change: ${Math.random().toString()}`);
  }, []);
  
  if (props.show) {
    return <div>{data}</div>;
  }
  return null
}

export default function Parent() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const onToggle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onToggle}>Toggle</button>
      <Child show={toggle}/>
    </>
  );
}
```